# Searching in PHP Nested Arrays

Tags: php

I've been digging in and learning as much as I can about PHP Arrays, but have hit a stumbling block that I cannot figure out.

In my example code, I have an array that looks like this:

```
$array = array("fruit" => array("apple", "orange", "pear"), "veg" => array("carrot","celery"));
```

Now, elsewhere in the code, I have a variable called $myfavouriteitem

```
$myfavouriteitem = "apple";
```

With the value of the `$myfavouriteitem` variable, I'd like to return the value `"fruit"`.

I've tried using `array_search()` function in PHP, but I'm not having luck. I was able to use `array_search()` until the point where I introduced the nested array.

If I'm approaching this from the wrong angle, please let me know. My initial thought on this was to use a database to store this information (especially since I'm new to arrays); however, that's out of the question for this particular project. With that in mind, my data sets will all have a one-to-many relationship (one key with multiple values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    if (in_array($myfavouriteitem, $val)) {
        echo $key;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks, Zerkms. I was able to get this to work for me. I am going to spend some more time reviewing PHP arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo key(array_filter($array, function ($values) use ($myfavouriteitem) { return in_array($myfavouriteitem, $values); }));
```

Needs PHP 5.3 though and may be slower than @zerkms solution. But hey, it's a functional one-liner! ;)